# Due volte la settimana o due volte alla settimana?

Tags: phrase-choice

Ciao, non capisco quale è giusto: "due volte *la* settimana" o "due volte *alla* settimana"? Oppure "due giorni la settimana, due giorni alla settimana"?

E uguale per il mese, l'anno? "Due giorni il mese", "Due volte l'anno", due giorni al mese, due giorni al anno?

Cerco le frasi in internet ma non trovo spiegazioni. Mi dicono che due giorni la settimana va bene, ma due giorni il mese suona male! C'e una regola?

Answer (score 3):

Secondo questo [articolo di Luca Serianni per l'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/una-risposta-a--alla--la-settimana/923), tutti questi costrutti distributivi sono perfettamente intercambiabili:

> - *all'anno* / *l'anno*
> - *al mese* / *il mese*
> - *alla settimana* / *la settimana*

Nell'articolo si spiega come nei primi secoli della storia della lingua questi costrutti si facevano senza la preposizione:

> I costrutti di questo tipo erano espressi nei primi secoli attraverso la reggenza diretta: "una fiata l'anno" (Brunetto Latini), "una volta il mese" (Boccaccio), "tre volte la settimana" (San Bernardino da Siena).

Ma poi alcuni scrittori cominciarono ad adoperare la preposizione articolata:

> Tra Quattro e Cinquecento, sembrerebbe soprattutto ad opera di scrittori non fiorentini, cominciano ad apparire le prime attestazioni con la preposizione articolata: "una fiata all'anno" (in un veneziano, il camaldolese Niccolò Manerbi o Malermi), "una volta al mese" (nel senese Pietro Fortini), "una fiata alla settimana" (in una delle relazioni di viaggio compilate da diversi autori ma raccolte, e all'occorrenza tradotte dal latino, dal trevigiano Giovan Battista Ramusio).

Nell'italiano moderno però le due possibilità sono stabilmente usate da un certo tempo:

> Successivamente le due possibilità si impiantano stabilmente nell'italiano letterario, come dimostra la convivenza dei costrutti presso il medesimo autore. Qualche esempio: "quaranta ducati all'anno" / "otto mila ducati l'anno" (Goldoni), "dieci scudi al mese" / "14 scudi il mese" (Leopardi), "a tanto al mese" / "a un tanto il mese" (Pirandello), "una volta alla settimana" / "due volte la settimana" (Tozzi).

Comment: Allora "un giorno il mese vado a Roma" va bene, o suona male anche se e giusto?